# Best practices for organizing frontend folders inside django

Tags: django, reactjs, vendor

I am using the Django framework and library React for doing my application.

At Django I insert my frontend code inside assets folder, so my question is if use a vendor folder for externals css/js is a good practice? 
if so how do I organize my code?

For example, I use the component [react-dates](https://github.com/airbnb/react-dates) and I have to edit .scss files.
My folder structure would be /assets/vendors/scss/ ?

Comment: It depends. Are you server rendering? If not, it might be better to make a new folder called "frontend" and put your react stuff there.

Comment: I am not server rendering, but I have to put my stuff inside assets folder because of Django